# Shareholder oppression, venture "growth at all costs", and bubbles

Tags: corporate-finance, economic-bubble, corporate-governance

Are "lifestyle businesses" more substantially likely to remain closely held corporations and commit shareholder oppression (business judgment rule)?

If so, does this have a substantial effect on VC bias for "unicorns"? (compared to, say, irrational risk/return analysis, or growth and moonshots actually being +EV compared to more mundane businesses) Or alternatively, is said bias a myth?